# Nested select box issue changing the first one

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building some logic ith 2 nested select box, basicly i load a json file and pass the data to an array in my vuejs component, the json contains the logic for the 2 select box for example for Business Developemnt i want to load in the second box Financial Proposal and Master Licence...:

```
{
    "Business Development": [
        {
            "text": "Financial Proposal",
            "key": 1
        },
        {
            "text": "Master Licence and Service Agreement",
            "key": 2
        },
        {
            "text": "Non-Disclosure Agreement",
            "key": 3
        },
        {
            "text": "Relatório de Missão",
            "key": 4
        }
    ],
    "Configuration Management": [
        {
            "text": "Configuration Management Plan",
            "key": 1
        },
        {
            "text": "Configuration Management Plan For Implementation Projects",
            "key": 2
        }
```

I already accomplish something like that, the issue is that when i change the first select box, the second is empty at position 1, like this:

[image]

**here is my code:**

```
<template>
  <div class="row margin-above2 box">
    <h3 class="text-center">Template</h3>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" class="img img-responsive" src="static/img/word.png">
      <form class="box-body form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" v-model="docData.documentType">
              <option v-for="(item,index) in documentNested">
                {{ index }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" v-model="docData.documentSelection">
              <option v-for="(item,index) in documentNested[docData.documentType]">{{item.text}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import data from '../../interfaceData/documentType.json'
import permissions from '../../interfaceData/permissions.json'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      checked: false,
      documentNested: data,
      permissions: permissions,
      listItems: [],
      documentData: []
    }
  },
```

thank you! :)

Comment: do you want to select the first available document as soon as document type changes?

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `value` bind of each option, that should be the value that option represents.

```
<option v-for="(item,index) in documentNested[docData.documentType]" :value="item">{{item.text}}</option>
```

and for an automatic selection when the first select changes, you can use a watcher

```
watch: {
    'docData.documentType'(val) {
        this.docData.documentSelection = this.documentNested[val][0];
    }
}
```

I tried to simulate your component here, maybe it help you

https://jsfiddle.net/9uke1596/

Comment: your solution is almost perfect, just have 1 issue the first time i don't get the element

Comment: if i delete the :value i get the first you know why?

Comment: you mean, if you open the 2nd select with no selection in the first select?

Comment: no i mean right at begin the second is empty, when i change everything is cool then, jus the first time the second is empty

Comment: it's empty cus `docData.documentType` is undefined until you select a value in the first select. When vue evaluate the second select, the `v-for="(item,index) in documentNested[docData.documentType]"` will do nothing, cus `documentNested[docData.documentType]` will also be undefined, resulting in no option for the second select.
You can accept my answer if it was correct :)

Comment: one thing you can do is select a default value, like the first document type. Add 
 `
  mounted() {
   this.docData.documentType = Object.keys(this.documentNested)[0];
  }
`

Comment: another issue is that my value for the second box is undefined

Comment: in my previous example it works
https://jsfiddle.net/yj826v8o/
maybe you wanna set a `:value` property in the first select as well